# Facebook error: "(#100) Invalid parameter", "OAuthException", "code":100

Tags: facebook, oauth, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

In my messenger platform app, when I make this request:

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/${psid}?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`
(to get users public info based on their PSID), sometimes Facebook returns this error:

`'There is an error when trying to get the user\'s info from Messenger:\nError: failed [400] {"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"FpUUkuX0egc"}}'`

I have no idea why this happens, because when I saw the error then I manually made the same request (by using POSTMAN), I got the correct result (user public profile) with no error.

Comment: I am having the same problem and am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with Postman since our node app with axios is returning the same error. No clue yet when it exactly occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for a **long long time** and finally managed to find the problem:

In one of my JSON's parameters, I had a value with an unknown character:

```
"יאל      בן רפל בהר"
```

instead of

```
 "יאל בן רפל בהר"
```

This character was **removed by POSTMAN**, and was later found out as a tab character (`\t`). Other, unknown characters were also removed.

The solution was to remove this value from the JSON along with other characters that may cause a bad request (such as tab):

```
value = value.Replace("\t", "").Replace("     ", "");
```

(This is a C# example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if POSTMAN is sending something in the headers in a different way that you are doing. It happened to me something similar and it was that POSTMAN was "correcting" something.

Compare the request from POSTMAN and the one you are doing with your app side by side.

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll look into another option. :)